# Which sobject stores the FieldPermissions for a profile.?

Tags: metadata, sobject

For a ProfileSet I see that field permissions are stored in the FieldPermissions sobject.
Does anyone know which sobjects stores the FieldPermissions for a Profile?
Thanks in advance

Comment: can you provide an example or screen which you are looking for

Answer (score 4):

The same object. Profiles are emulated through to PermissionSet, but the PS will have the ProfileId field set as the Profile's Id, and IsOwnedByProfile will be true/checked.

Comment: The only columns for FieldPermissions sobject are  
Id,ParentId,SobjectType,Field,PermissionsEdit,PermissionsREad,SystemModstamp  

ParentId is referenced to 'PermissionSet' sobject.  

I tried to search for the 'System Administrator' profile's field permissions using its Id(00e500000017Wia) but did not get any FieldPermissions back.  

select Id,ParentId,SobjectType,Field from FielPermissions where Id = '00e500000017Wia'  
Would appreciate the soal anyone provide to find the FieldPermissions for say  'System Administrator' profile.